# Libav (ffmpeg) what is the purpose of a container codec timebase and also a stream timebase?

Tags: c, video, ffmpeg, codec, libav

I saw this answer, [Libav (ffmpeg) copying decoded video timestamps to encoder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40275242/libav-ffmpeg-copying-decoded-video-timestamps-to-encoder)

But I still don't understand why we need both the stream timebase and the codec timebase. Currently I'm trying to write some code that determines the time at which a frame is shown in a video from my decoder so I think the right way to do that is like this

`aVFrame.best_effort_timestamp * stream.time_base.num * stream.time_base.den` is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

"why we need both" is a loaded statement. We don't NEED both. Your question should be why do we HAVE both.

This is not an ffmpeg/libav invention, it is a side effect of how media files work. Some (but not all) codecs have a mechanism for encoding a time base into the codec bitstream (for example h.264). These bitstreams can then be written/muxed to a container (for example mp4) that also encodes a timebase. In theory these should match, but in practice they often do not. libav is just parsing the file and populating the structs with what is there.